# Where can I find proof of Rufus "Red" McMurtry's fate?

Tags: hero-u

I asked the Librarian, who told me all about him, but won't give me any books or documents as proof for Hans.

I've definitely heard his name before. I thought I came across a painting of him, but I can't seem to find it again.

In addition to the paintings, I've also looked at all the plaques in the catacombs again. Although its possible that I missed it because I found it extremely tedious to crawl through there again.

Where can I find something about this to help Hans? (If it is a plaque in the catacombs, please say which room!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. I stumbled across it while picking locks

> on the cabinets in the Hall of Heroes

for want of anything better to do. You know, as you do.